# Store iPhone Location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, mkmapview

I am trying to write an iPhone app that will store a user's initial location with the touch of a button. Then, they can press a button later that will show them their final location in relation to their initial location in a MapView. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the FAQ so you can get higher quality answers to your questions.

Please provide some information as to exactly what you want, what you have tried so far, and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather broad question.

There are a few pieces to this task:

1. Getting the location.
2. Saving the location somewhere.
3. Retrieving the location.

For the first, look at [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

For the second and third, the easiest option is probably [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

here this is mini tutorial about use location..

here add framework `CoreLocation`

First set delegate in .h file like   
and also import this line on .h or also in .m file add this line `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`.

Then in .m go:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D here =  newLocation.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"%f  %f ", here.latitude, here.longitude);
}
```

also when you want to store location then on you button tap event just get newLocation like above method from `locationManager`

here `locationManager` delegate methods  `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` method will get pinged every time Core Location has something to say to you, which should happen every few seconds. those CLLocation objects contain info about accuracy, so you can screen for good points in that method.
Be sure to call `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]` and then `[locationManager release]` at some point!